# Flash not cleared when using exceptions_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in our Rails application we use custom errors by doing: `config.exceptions_app = self.routes`

and

```
%w[401 403 404 500].each do |code|
  get code, to: 'errors#show', defaults: { code: code }
end
```

We also use Devise for our authentication.

We've noticed a weird edge case whereby when the user logs in and is shown a flash message of signed in successfully but hits an error immediately the flash is displayed but if the user refreshes the page the flash will be displayed again and again and is never cleared.

If they visit another page that doesn't have the error then they will see the flash again (because it wasn't cleared) but it will then clear successfully. So it seems that the exceptions_app somehow bypasses the clearing of flashes in Rails...

To fix this we've done:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    flash.clear # clear all flashes
    render params[:code].to_s, status: params[:code]
  end
end
```

So we clear the flashes on the error so they are not seen again afterwards...

Any ideas why this is happening? Is this a bug in Rails' exceptions_app?

Comment: What do you mean "If the user logs in successfully,  but hits an error immediately" how does this actually occur? What error is being hit? It sounds like a js timing issue.

Comment: Nothing to do with JS. Error as in an exception. So for example I could just do `raise StandardError` on a controller method that gets hit after a successful login.

Comment: What version of Rails?  Might be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33447

Comment: @lacostenycoder 5.2.1

Comment: Are you aware that reloading the action with the error will probably just rerun the login part and than fail for the same reason? You login the user everyone and therefore the the message again and again.

Comment: @spickermann That's not true. At this stage the login has happened and none of the devise logic is being called. It's purely a case of the session not being cleared when run through the exceptions_app.